# ArrayList in alphabetical order (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a method that puts each string in a string array list in alphabetical order as the strings are entered. For example, if I enter 4 as the size of the desired array list and enter Anne, Bill, Aran, Carol, the method should print Anne, Aran, Bill, Carol. However, right now it only prompts me for 3 strings and does not print out anything. Instead it gives this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2." Why is it giving me this error?

```
public static ArrayList<String> getOrderedListOfNames()
{
    System.out.println ("How big an array?");
    int size = sc.nextInt ();
    ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>(size);

    System.out.println ("Type in a string");
    String firstInput= sc.next();
    names.add(firstInput);
    System.out.println ("Type in a string");
    String secInput= sc.next();
    if (secInput.compareTo(firstInput)>0)
        names.add(secInput);
    else
        names.add(0,secInput);
    if (size>2)
    {
        for (int i = 2 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Type in a string");
            String input= sc.next();
            int entered=0;
            for (int j=0; j<names.size(); j++)
            {
                String name1=names.get(j);
                String name2=names.get(j+1);
                if (input.compareTo(name1)>0 && input.compareTo(name2)<0)
                {
                    names.add(j+1, input );
                    entered=1;
                    j=names.size();
                }

            }
            if (entered==0)
                names.add(input);
        }
    }
    return names;

}
```

Comment: If you get errors, then always provide the full StackTrace and mark the line that causes this Exception. The problem is this line: `String name2=names.get(j+1);`. `j` can reach the value `names.size() - 1`, therefore `j+1` will be an index, that does not exist in the list. In this case, index `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for list of size 2 ( for example `["a", "b"]`) you are traversing from 0 to 1 in `j` but you do `j + 1` that means for 1 you will try to access `2` which is definitely out of bound

either go upto `< size - 1` or just use [`Collections.sort(yourArrayList)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0):

first build your array

second iterate using a comparator:

```
class LexicographicComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
    }
}



//... your code
 Collections.sort(list, new LexicographicComparator());
```